# Error while installing cmake for Avogadro

Tags: software-installation, cmake

While trying to add extensions in Avogadro, I have installed all the pre-requisites required - cmake, eigen, openbbel, Qt.

I am following [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250083/how-do-i-install-avogadro-from-source-after-receiving-the-error-below), and have reached as far as the following steps:

> 1. Create a `build` directory in the package source directory.
>
>    ```
>    mkdir build
>    cd build
>    ```
> 2. Configure the build system
>
>    ```
>    cmake ../
>    ```

After doing the `cmake ../` command, I get the following error:

```
'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Kindly help me where I am wrong.

Comment: Proof please that cmake is installed ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `cmake`:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Comment: hello thankx for ur reply...I have new problem now..i successfully installed evertyhing wat evr required..but now while compiling in Qt I m facing problem.... I am getting following msg  "No rule to make target `all' "